# Turn off pop up when typing "with open(..." in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, popup

Whenever I use `with open()`, I'll get a big popup window that blocks most of my screen, like so:

[image: screenshot]

I tried looking for ways to disable it, but have not found any. Does anyone know how I can turn this off?

Comment: Try menu options Help | Find action | Code completion, settings

Answer (score 0):

Found it with the help of [BoarGules](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2084384/boargules)' reply.

I went to: `Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion`

Under **"Parameter Info"**, I unchecked the **"Show the parameter info popup in ~ ms"**.